# All h2 text in one <div> overwrite

Tags: css

I can't separate the h2 text in one , here's the picture[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxxbL.png

this is the html:

```
<div class="card">
    <h2>Youtube</h2>
    <h2>Instagram</h2>
    <h2>Pixnet</h2>
</div>
```

this is the css:

```
.card h2{
position: absolute;
top:100px;
bottom: 100px;
text-align:left;
display:block;
line-height: 2em;}
```

thank you!

Comment: it cannot be absolute change it to relative.

Comment: @Maggie I hope my answer solved your issue. If this is the case, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please let me know what I can improve.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `position: absolute` for this:

```css
.card h2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h2>Youtube</h2>
  <h2>Instagram</h2>
  <h2>Pixnet</h2>
</div>
```

`display: block` is the default for `h2` elements. `text-align: left` is also the default you can remove it. For spacings, you can use the `margin` and `padding` property. The `padding` will make the element bigger than the width/height unless you use `box-sizing: border-box`, which is recommended. Use `margin` for the spacing outside and `padding` for spacing inside.

You have to understand how the position attribute works:

**Static positioning**
All the HTML elements are by default `position: static`.
They are always positioned inside the parent element and inherit attributes from the parent and they override the parent attributes that are applied to the element itself.

**Absolute positioning**
When you use `position: absolute` the elements will be placed inside the last node that has `position: relative`. If there is no node in the DOM higher in the hierarchy with `position: relative`, then it will be placed at `[parent.x, parent.y]`, otherwise at `[relative-parent.x, relative-parent.y]`. The `position: absolute` will take the element out of the content-flow - it does not interfere with the rest of the DOM anymore i.e. it is on a different layer. You have to do the positioning yourself with the `left, right, top, bottom` attributes.

**Fixed positioning**
`position: fixed` is always relative to the viewport. So you can't scroll on fixed elements. It is always exactly at coordinate `[x, y]`.

**Sticky positioning**
There is also the `position: sticky`. But I won't cover that here.

**References**
If you are interested you can read here:

[css-positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
[css-box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using `position: absolute`.

When using `absolute` you need to also define the position using `top`, `down`, `left`, `right`. E.g. `top: 4px` - otherwise the default coordinates are at the top left of the container.

Try changing position to `relative` instead. You can use `top`/`left` etc with it but the `h2`'s will not stack